# Method or data member not found error in Worksheet var

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that allows the user to open a file using filepicker

```
Sub SelectFile()

    Dim sFileName  As Variant

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("MS Excel (*.csv), *.xlxs")

    If sFileName = False Then

        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbInformation, "Warning!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Sheets("Main").txtSrc.Value = sFileName

End Sub
```

when I'm trying to change `Sheets("Main").txtSrc.Value = sFileName` to `ws.txtSrc.Value = sFileName`, it returns the method or data member not found error. By the way, `txtSrc` is an ActiveX Control textbox. Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Worksheet` class does not have a `txtSrc` property. Declare the `ws` variable as `Object` or as the specific sheet interface (its code name).

Comment: No it is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Shapes("txtSrc").OLEFormat.Object.object.value
```

Comment: Why the `...OLEFormat.Object.object...` ? Particularly the `...Object.object...` part?